# UIImage not in wanted location of UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

Problem solved, s. comment on first answer...

I am using a plugin called [Carlos](https://github.com/WeltN24/Carlos) to load images from the cache if they have already been fetched once. However, the images I load only appear in the first of my (3) pages (I have a `scrollView` with `pagingEnabled` set to `true` and each of these pages shall contain the `userProfilePicture`). In addition to that, the image(s) appearing on the first page also has(-ve) no offsets. Combining those two informations one can assume that all (3 due to 3 pages) images are currently located on the first page with an offset of 0 and 0 for x and y respectively (see image below)(therefore I added '(s)' and '(-ve)' previously). How can I place the loaded image in the UIImageView? Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?

### Code (Swift)

```
let userProfilePicture: UIImageView = {

    let statusBarHeight = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height

    let profileImageFrame = CGRect(x: statusBarHeight / 2, y: statusBarHeight, width: 50, height: 50)
    let profileImageView = UIImageView(frame: profileImageFrame)

    //set backgroundcolor (placeholder as sort of a place holder)
    profileImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, alpha: 0.5)

    let imageUrl = NSURL(string: "https://like.to.myImageWith50pixels.jpg")!

    let cache = MemoryCacheLevel().compose(DiskCacheLevel()).compose(NetworkFetcher())

    cache.get((imageUrl as NetworkFetcher.KeyType) as NetworkFetcher.KeyType)
        .onSuccess { value in
            let profileImage = UIImage(data: value as Data)


            profileImageView.image = profileImage
        }
        .onFailure { error in
            print("An error occurred :( \(error)")
    }

    profileImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    //round picture
    profileImageView.layer.borderWidth = 1
    profileImageView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    profileImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 0.75, green: 0.75, blue: 0.75, alpha: 0.75).cgColor
    profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = profileImageView.frame.height/2
    profileImageView.clipsToBounds = true

    return profileImageView

}()
```

[image: All three images are probably underneath one another]

Answer (score 0):

one more solution I made it. Make a singleton class with a NSCache parameter. using GCD fetch images and save image data for location key.

for every time you want image. use singleton class NSCache parameter to fetch and image from web or local cache which every is available first.

Comment: This would probably work, too but after looking at my code in the question, I saw that `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` was still set to `false`. I thought about setting it to `true` and found it should make sense... which it did, it works: Long story short, problem solved... just set it to `true`. Thank you, nonetheless!